# TYPO3 Preview URL Configuration

Tags: url, typo3, preview

Struggling to implement an additional query string to the preview URL

Found documentation here:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/7.2/Feature-66370-AddFlexiblePreviewUrlConfiguration.html

But I can't implement it.

To clarify, I want to add a new query string when previewing a page (specifically a custom page type, but adding a query string for all pages would be a good start!)

I've tried adding this

```
page = PAGE
page {
    TCEMAIN.preview {
        pages {
            additionalGetParameters {
                newQueryString = property1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but no joy - please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're mixing TypoScript-setup for the template-record with the syntax for PageTS in the page-properties.
`TCEMAIN` is usually used in PageTS or UserTS and is not available in TypoScript-setup for templates.
So you just have to use the following code in the TS field of the page-properties of the root-page:

```
TCEMAIN.preview {
    pages {
        additionalGetParameters {
            newQueryString = tx_ngkpagetypes_sitesettings_languageversion
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This only edits the function of the "Save and view page" button - do you know how to edit the View webpage buttons? I need to add the query string to every instance of "view webpage" possible to prevent confusion with the users

Comment: Glad I could help. I'd advise to open another question concerning your other problem and describe it a bit more. I'll be informed about the question if you tag it (like this on) with `typo3`

Comment: Added a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52384218/typo3-preview-url-configuration-for-all-buttons