# TYPO3 Preview URL Configuration for all buttons

Tags: url, typo3, preview

I need to add a query string to the preview URL on TYPO3.

There are 4 possible ways to view the page from TYPO3 BE

- Edit the page and choose "Save and view page" from the "Save" button dropdown
- Right click on page in page tree
- Click "document with eye" icon "View webpage" button (under Columns/Languages dropdown)
- Click "eye" icon "View webpage" under default when Languages is selected

Using this configuration:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/7.6/Changelog/7.2/Feature-66370-AddFlexiblePreviewUrlConfiguration.html
I am able to edit the "Save and view page" option to add a query string like so:

```
TCEMAIN.preview {
    pages {
        additionalGetParameters {
            newQueryString = tx_languageversion2
        }
    }
}
```

Is there equivalent code to edit the other view page buttons listed above?

EDIT: Alternatively, is there a way to hide the View button next to the Edit button? That way the only way to preview is using the "Save and view page" option

Thanks

Comment: According to the name of your class the desired URL-parameter would be related to language. So why you think you need add there some functionality, aren't the language-related options in TYPO3 not enough?

Comment: Hi David, it's a client request so I do need this extra parameter. Do you know if it's possible to add a query string to these other button actions?

Comment: I suppose somehow it might be possible but currently I don't know how. Apart from that I suggest you to describe a bit more why you need it to elaborate if it's really needed or if there is another way to reach your goal.

Comment: Hi David, do you know why it's easy to edit the "Save and view page" button, but not the others? Surely all the buttons labelled "view page" should have the same behaviour? Or have I misunderstood? Thanks

Comment: I understood the question itself quite well, just not the reason for it. Regrettable I can't help with it in the moment.

Comment: is there a way to hide the View button next to the Edit button? That way the only way to preview is using the "Save and view page" option

Comment: which version of TYPO3 are you using?

Comment: version - 8.7.17